# In Linked/Related questions list mark the questions with a status tag (Meta sites only)

Tags: feature-request, meta, per-site-meta, related-questions, linked-questions

On meta sites (both per-site and MSE), I don't really care for accepted answer. What I do care about is the status of a bug report or feature request.

Currently, the Related/Linked questions in the sidebar got a different color when the question has an accepted answer. This is useful on main sites, however on meta sites (including here on MSE), I would prefer to have a different color for questions having a status tag on them.

For example, the Related questions list for [this question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286490/short-post-links-with-a-trailing-slash-dont-onebox-in-chat) would look like this:

> [image]

This way I can easily know "those are handled", instead of "those got accepted answer", which is not really helpful on meta sites.

Comment: If there's *also* a way to distinguish positive from negative status-* tags, I'm sure this would be even better.

Comment: @Nathan true, I considered asking for that as well, but realized it might become too complicated. Better start with simple request, and then who knows... :)

Answer (score 5):

Color's not a great way to distinguish status. (Colorblindness is fairly common, after all.)

I suggest that any question with a `status-*` tag on it be displayed with *Italics*.

That won't change the aesthetics of the related question list design, but will still convey that certain of the questions are *different*.